# ¿Qué es "tomar por la retambufa"?

Tags: vocabulario, modismos, expresiones, significado, vulgaridades

En [este blog](http://elcapitanachab.blogspot.com.es/2007/12/por-probar-probar.html) he encontrado el texto

> Decía el difunto Jaime Campmany que él lo había probado todo menos montar en globo y tomar por la retambufa.

En el [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?w=retambufa) no figura "retambufa".

En [quesignifica.com](http://que-significa.com/significado.php?termino=retambufa) recogen dos acepciones, aparentemente específicas de Argentina:

> "retambufa" en glosario de lunfardo y giros de Argentina:
>   **Bujarrón, homosexual activo.**
>   "retambufa" en glosario de jergas y modismos de Argentina:
>   **(lunf.) Retaguardia/ pederasta activo/ lesbiana activa/ coito anal.**

¿Es "**tomar por la retambufa**" un sinónimo de "**coito anal**"? Siendo "retambufa", al parecer, una palabra exclusiva de Argentina ¿se utiliza la expresión en otras regiones? ¿Está muy extendido su uso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hoy el término *retambufa* es prácticamente desconocido en Argentina, un miembro de la [Academia Porteña del Lunfardo](http://www.lunfardo.org.ar) en su [Comunicación Académica Nº 18](http://www.lunfardo.org.ar/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/COMUNICACIO%CC%81N-ACADE%CC%81MICA-N%C2%BA-18.pdf), de mayo de 1964 propone el siguiente significado y etimología:

> RETAMBUFA
>
> Bufarrón. A la abreviatura *bufa* se adicionan actualmente el afijo que actúa, en este caso, como prefijo modificatorio, en el sentido de apoyar, refirmar; sumándose *tam*, voz onomatopéyica, demostrativa de rotundez, empuje, sonoro y sin desfallecimiento. En suma: el ahora circulante *retambufa* para designar al *bufa* habitual, recalcitrante, rotundo.

Es decir que un *retambufa* sería alguien *muy bufarrón*. *Bufarrón* sí es un término conocido hoy por cualquiera en Argentina y significa *homosexual* (en forma más bien despectiva).

Sin embargo, como tú has encontrado, *retambufa* aparece como equivalente a *trasero* o *culo* en listados de palabras del [murciano](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialecto_murciano) como [éste](https://www.saberespractico.com/curiosidades/diccionario-murciano-espanol-por-orden-alfabetico/).

Osvaldo Bazán, en su libro [Historia de la homosexualidad en la Argentina](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=1aISuTfXO3UC&pg=PA148&lpg=PA148) cuenta que [Roberto Lehmann-Nitsche](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roberto_Lehmann_Nitsche) publicó en 1923 un libro en el que encuentra lo siguiente:

> Buceando en el vocabulario lunfardo de fin del siglo XIX, se encontró el alemán en Ensenada con varias palabras que designaban al homosexual [...] Registra también "dar por retambufa" como coito anal y anota que retambufa es retaguardia, de aquí "retambufero", el pederasta activo. "Recibir por retambufa", "llevar por detrás", "recibir por el orto" son expresiones que "equivalen a practicar la sodomía".

Así que lo que me parece más probable es que el término haya sido introducido en Argentina por inmigrantes murcianos. Como la palabra se usaba allí únicamente en ese contexto debe haber pasado de significar *trasero* a *sodomita*.

Mientras, en España, la palabra sigue siendo equivalente de *culo*. Como dice el blog que citas, mucha gente la conoce por [Jaime Campmany](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaime_Campmany), murciano. Así que *tomar por la retambufa* quiere decir simplemente ***tomar por culo***. Supongo que proviene de *retaguardia*. Esto es consistente con que a veces se encuentra *por retambufa* usado como equivalente a *por detrás*, en el sentido de *a traición*.

Un poco de Google muestra que la palabra actualmente solo aparece en la prensa o blogs españoles. Un par de ejempos:

- [Retambufa](http://www.abc.es/20100220/opinion-firmas/retambufa-20100220.html)
- [El inglés ataca por retambufa](http://blogs.elconfidencial.com/espana/palo-alto/2013-08-10/el-ingles-ataca-por-retambufa_16847/)
- [Dios mío, hasta Gandhi era vasioleta](http://web.eldia.es/criterios/2011-04-15/5-Dios-mio-Gandhi-era-vasioleta.htm)

Comment: Tras leer tu respuesta, he encontrado un diccionario murciano-español en https://www.saberespractico.com/curiosidades/diccionario-murciano-espanol-por-orden-alfabetico/ que recoge: **Retambufa: Trasero, culo. “Dar por retambufa”** lo que apoya tu respuesta

Comment: @user13560 esto me hace pensar que el origen no es el propuesto por la cita que puse, sino que debe haber sido introducido en Argentina por inmigrantes murcianos en el siglo XIX

Comment: @user13560 actualicé mi respuesta con más información y esta interpretación.